# Can you actually declare the data type for a variable in python?

Tags: python, variables, types, type-hinting, python-typing

I just learned that you can define what kind of value you want a variable to hold using the syntax "x: type". But when I actually try it myself in Visual Studio Code, nothing seems to happen. For example, if I write:

```
x: int
x = 'number'
print(x)
```

it just prints the word 'number', and I don't get any kind of warning about it. I'm using Python 3.9 and don't have any other version installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Types in python are not tested at runtime, you need to verify them via something like http://mypy-lang.org "at compile time", like this:

```sh
(venv) rasjani@MacBook-Pro ~/src/test$ cat test.py
x: int
x = 'number'
print(x)
(venv) rasjani@MacBook-Pro ~/src/test$ mypy test.py
test.py:2: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "str", variable has type "int")
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
(venv) rasjani@MacBook-Pro ~/src/test$
```